# Why 3 Xform-Objects in JavaFX 3D Molecule Example

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a question related to the [MoleculeSampleApp in the Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/sampleapp.htm). In the function `buildCamera()` they create three objects of type `Xform` and additionally add the camera to the third one. Why do i need this three nested `Xform-Objects? Thanks in advance!

```
private void buildCamera() {
    root.getChildren().add(cameraXform);
    cameraXform.getChildren().add(cameraXform2);
    cameraXform2.getChildren().add(cameraXform3);
    cameraXform3.getChildren().add(camera);
    cameraXform3.setRotateZ(180.0);

    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-cameraDistance);
    cameraXform.ry.setAngle(320.0);
    cameraXform.rx.setAngle(40);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admittedly, I've been struggling with the seeming vacuum of JavaFX 3D resources, and the lack of thoroughness in the few resources that I've found. However, I've come up with a satisfying guess.

### The transformations are split and nested so that they are performed in order.

Specifically, each `Node` (and every class you work with is a subclass of `Node`) has its own list of transformations. The `Group` class is a special subclass of `Node` designed, as far as I can tell, to be a general container of other JavaFX `Node`s. The [Oracle documentation for `Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) says:

> Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group.

As a result, an instance of `XForm` (a `Group` subclass that bundles all of the possible transformations together) inside of another `XForm` will apply the outer transformation and then the inner transformation to anything on the inside.

In this case the transformations aren't named very well, but `cameraXform` is used exclusively for x/y rotation, `cameraXform2` is used exclusively for x/y translation, and `cameraXform3` is used exclusively for z rotation*. The order (and by extension, the nesting) is important because rotations are performed about the axes; translating first will cause the scene to react in unintuitive ways to the user's input.

*The z rotation (which is set exactly once in the sample app), as far as I can tell, is used so that the y axis is pointed up instead of the JavaFX default of y down. This allows the shapes to be added in the commonly accepted x/y/z axis orientation, while allowing them to be rendered in JavaFX's own orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is how they were able to make smooth "accurate" transformations without exposing the Affine transform (which has much more relevance in 3D).